# Hay alguna manera de seleccionar un valor en un SPINNER y mostrar otro relacionado con este ultimo?

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

Tengo una BD de SQLite con una tabla con dos campos, Ciente e Id

Ej: Cliente: Pepe Perez
Id: 453475

Alimento el SPINNER con el campo Cliente.

Cuando el usuario seleccione Pepe Perez necesito que se quede seleccionado el Id de Pepe Perez.

Sabeis si esto es posible en Android?

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Crea una variable global en la clase llamada id inicializala en 0:

```
int idUser = 0;
```

en el metodo de seleccion del spinner configuras que cada que se de click en un spinner tu variable tome el valor de ese usuario ejemplo:

Suponiendo que ya declaraste tu spinner:

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
               idUser = (manda a llamar el id del usuario);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
              idUser = 0;
            }
        });
```

De esta forma cada que seleccione un usuario quedara seleccionado su id de manera global y puedes trabajar con el como gustes